# RNN Not Generalizing on Text Classification

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am using keras and RNN to classify slack text data on whether the text is reaction worthy or not (1 - emoji, 0 - no emoji). I have removed usernames and urls from the text as well as dropped duplicates with different target variables.

I am not able to get the model to generalize to unseen data. The loss of the train/val sets look good and continually decrease but the accuracy of the val set only decreases.

I am using a pretrained GLOVE word embedding since my training size is only about 25,000 sentences.

I have added additional layers, changed my regularization value and increased dropout but get similar results. Is my model not complex enough to generalize the data? The times i added additional layers they were much smaller but deeper because the training time was about 2 min per epoch.

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                       100,
                       weights=[embeddings_matrix],
                       input_length=max_message_length,
                       embeddings_regularizer=l2(0.001),
                       trainable=True)
# Creating the Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(layers.GRU(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compiling the model with our given Optimizer

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.000025)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "reaction worth"? Predicting if a text post will get likes/upvotes is a really hard problem. It's not surprising if your RNN doesn't generalize. Try looking at some examples from your data and predicting the label by hand. If you can't do any better than random chance then your RNN will probably have a hard time too.

Comment: Yeah in slack "reactions" are just emoji's people can put on your message.